# Need NIC driver for Proliant DL380 G4 NIC=NC7782

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

I have installed Windows 2003 Server Enterprise Edition (32bit) on a Proliant server but can not seem to find the driver for the NIC. I have spent hours looking with no luck.

Would like to just point device manager to a .sys file or similar and be done with it. I found an HP web site rahter easily but the link is a dead end.

Help!

Answer (score 9):

Seriously? I just went to HP.com, clicked on drivers, typed in NC7782, chose W2K3 32-bit and it links to all [THESE](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=407733&prodTypeId=329290&prodSeriesId=407731&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1005) drivers and firmware updates.

Don't come here again if you're going to be that lazy.

Comment: Same thing I did; however, the driver did not work. I'm not sure why, didn't recognize the card. Another post on the forum did provide me with a url that worked so I'll be sure to return the favor.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go... It's a Broadcom 5704 chipset.

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=3288132&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=397634&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1005#11395

Or

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=397634&prodNameId=3288132&swEnvOID=1005&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-0e5582514a6a406ca216e6135f

Or

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Home.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=329290&prodSeriesId=407731